# how to invisible recyclerview item getting value from spinner

Tags: android

I want when user click on "قرآن" my program invisible else things mean tarjuma and tafsir,

same like when he clicks on "مع ترجمہ" my program visible Quran and tarjuma and hide the tafsir.

I am using [spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urrjo.png) it works fine but after refresh my recyclerview but I want without refreshing the recyclerview, mean is that when the user selects any Spinner value recyclerview change the view.

refresh mean going to another activity.

anybody who help me!!

here is my RecyclerView Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Quran quran = quranic.get(position);
    if (Quran.spinner.equals("قرآن")) {
        holder.quran.setText(Html.fromHtml(quran.getQuranText()));
        holder.reference.setText(quran.getReferences());
        holder.tarjuma.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.tafsir.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (Quran.spinner.equals("مع ترجمہ")) {
        holder.quran.setText(Html.fromHtml(quran.getQuranText()));
        holder.tarjuma.setText(Html.fromHtml(quran.getTarjuma()));
        holder.reference.setText(quran.getReferences());
        holder.tafsir.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.quran.setText(Html.fromHtml(quran.getQuranText()));
        holder.tarjuma.setText(Html.fromHtml(quran.getTarjuma()));
        holder.tafsir.setText(Html.fromHtml(quran.getTafsir()));
        holder.reference.setText(quran.getReferences());
    }
}
```

my MainActivity

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.visibility);
List<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
spinnerList.add(0, "Select");
spinnerList.add(1, "قرآن");
spinnerList.add(2, "مع ترجمہ");
spinnerList.add(3, "مع تفسیر");
ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Select")) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Quran.spinner = item;
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Quran.java

```
public static String spinner = "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your recycler view adapter each time you select an item from your spinner.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Select")) {
                    // do nothing
                } else {
                    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Quran.spinner = item;
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView != null ? recyclerView.getAdapter() : null;
                    if (adapter != null) {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Even better if you keep a reference to your recycler view adapter, then replace:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView != null ? recyclerView.getAdapter() : null;
     if (adapter != null) {
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

by:

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.visibility);
            List<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
            spinnerList.add(0, "Select");
            spinnerList.add(1, "قرآن");
            spinnerList.add(2, "مع ترجمہ");
            spinnerList.add(3, "مع تفسیر");
            ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Select")) {
                        // do nothing
                    } else {
                        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Quran.spinner = item;
                  //add this line 
                        yourAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
```